# abstracting data-type heterogeneity of different database

Tags: java, database, wsdl

In my current  project, I have a requirement of abstracting data-type heterogeneity among different database.

For instance,  I have a table in MySQL database. Table name is `FIRSTTABLE(badgeID *Integer* , pref INT)`.

I have a table in Apache-Derby database. Table name is `FIRSTTABLE (badgeID *varchar(12)*, pref INT)`.

Now,  query component, which queries MySQL database and Apache Derby database at same time, has badgeID as "double".

My requirement is that query-component should not know underlying database (either MySQL or Apache Derby). Its query should be independent of type of database.

How could I resolve this issue ? My research problem is not limited to MySQL or Apach-Derby. For clarity, I have taken an example of Apache-Derby and MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write an adapter.  Your adapter could be one Java class or more than one Java class.

Based on your example, it would look something like this.

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

    private DatabaseType type;

    public DatabaseAdapter(DatabaseType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ResultSet selectFirstTable(double badgeID) {
        if (type == DatabaseType.Derby) {
            String s = Double.toString(badgeID);
            return derbySelectFirstTable(s);
        } else if (type == DatabaseType.MySQL) {
            int i = (int) badgeID;
            return mysqlSelectFirstTable(i);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}

public enum DatabaseType {
    MySQL, Derby
}
```

Another, better way of coding this is to use an interface.  Again, using your example, the code would look something like this.

```
public interface Database {
    public ResultSet selectFirstTable(double badgeID);
}

public class MySQLDatabase implements Database {

    public ResultSet selectFirstTable(double badgeID) {
         int i = (int) badgeID;
         // code to select first table in MySQL
    }

}

public class DerbyDatabase implements Database {

    public ResultSet selectFirstTable(double badgeID) {
        String s = Double.toString(badgeID);
        // code to select first table in Derby
    }

}
```

Somewhere in your code, you would initialize the Database interface with the correct data base type.

```
Database database = null;
if (type == DatabaseType.MySQL) {
    database = new MySQLDatabase();
} else if (type == DatabaseType.Derby) {
    database = new DerbyDatabase();
}
```